# Union in C#, Structure with Array

Tags: c#

Hi there I am trying to understand this code in C++ and trying to understand a way to write it into my C# code (in C# language)

```
typedef struct
{
   unsigned short    A;
   FaultStatStruct  AA;
   unsigned long     AAA;
   unsigned short   AAAA;
   
} AStruct;


// Define NVM word to struct converter
union
{
   AStruct A_record;
   unsigned short A_words[64];
} converter;
```

So, essentially, it is marrying the structure Astruct with the data in A_words, creating A_record. I could be wrong; if I am, please let me know.

Comment: Are you trying todo interop with an unmanged API or for what do you need this for?

Comment: in the code the A_words[64]  array is being filled with hex code from a file,  no API is involved

Comment: Well, `fopen` (C stdlib) and `CreateFile` (Win32) are APIs, just not a *Web* API. Either of those might be used in the process of reading a file.

Comment: Gotcha. I am using system.io.streamreader for the C# code. But I'm confused about the union here. Is there a similar process that I still need to include?

Comment: Unless you need these structures because you are -- as Ralf asked -- trying to interop with something like an unmanaged API that requires them, you should rewrite it using idiomatic C#. So back to Ralf's question: are you trying to do interop with an unmanaged API?

Comment: is that what the union is doing? because from this C++ code I am looking at it is reading the line via ptr=buffer;
               ptr=ptr+2;
               sscanf(ptr, "%lX", &temp_lo);

Comment: The union is saying that `A_record` and `A_words` occupy memory starting at the same starting point, and the C code is using pointer arithmetic to fill `A_words` using `A_record`-colored glasses (or vice-versa, maybe). What the C code is doing, C# considers unsafe. You have to use specialized facilities to do this kind of thing. That's why it's better to rewrite it using idiomatic C#. To do that, you have to understand what it's doing separate from how it's doing it.